# using masked array to create pandas DataFrame

Tags: arrays, numpy, pandas

Thinking I'm getting the following behaviour b/c my input array is masked, which I'm having a hard time understanding. I've been looking at [this pandas doc on gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions), but not really sure what a "sentinel" value is. Is it just something like "-9999" that one uses during the creation of the DataFrame which is subsequently set to NULL?

What is a good way to handle these values when making a DataFrame? I'm happy if the masked entries are set to NULL.

Here's an example:

```
[Dbg]>>> segDF = pd.DataFrame(segArrNew)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\esri\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 393, in __init__
    datacopy[mask] = NA
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 3027, in __setitem__
    ndarray.__setitem__(_data, indx, dval)
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

[Dbg]>>> segArrNew
masked_array(data = [(1, u'01', 1, --) (2, u'01', 2, --) (3, u'01', 3, --) ...,
 (56853, u'21', 241, --) (56854, u'21', 242, --) (56855, u'21', 243, --)],
             mask = [(False, False, False, True) (False, False, False, True)
 (False, False, False, True) ..., (False, False, False, True)
 (False, False, False, True) (False, False, False, True)],
       fill_value = (999999, u'N/A', 999999, u'N/A'),
            dtype = [('seg_id_nat', '<i4'), ('region', '<U255'), ('seg_id_reg', '<i4'), ('refGage', '<U30')])
```

You can see that the array is masked and that some of the first few rows show examples of `--` in there. So I drop the last field (`refGage`) and it works, so I think it's masked values which only appear in that field.

```
[Dbg]>>> segArrNew2 = npFuncs.drop_fields(segArrNew, ['refGage'])
[Dbg]>>> segDF = pd.DataFrame(segArrNew2)
[Dbg]>>> segDF
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 57186 entries, 0 to 57185
Data columns:
seg_id_nat    57186  non-null values
region        57186  non-null values
seg_id_reg    57186  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-a-series

Comment: Also possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68532200/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-masked-array/68534675

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the "best-est" way to do this, but I converted the masked array  to a regular `numpy.ndarray` using the `numpy.ma.filled()` function ([options listed in this doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#to-a-ndarray)).

```
[Dbg]>>> np.ma.filled(segArrNew)
array([(1, u'01', 1, u'N/A'), (2, u'01', 2, u'N/A'), (3, u'01', 3, u'N/A'),
       ..., (56853, u'21', 241, u'N/A'), (56854, u'21', 242, u'N/A'),
       (56855, u'21', 243, u'N/A')], 
      dtype=[('seg_id_nat', '<i4'), ('region', '<U255'), ('seg_id_reg', '<i4'), ('refGage', '<U30')])

[Dbg]>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.ma.filled(segArrNew))
[Dbg]>>> df.ix[df['refGage'] == u'N/A'], 'refGage'] = ''
```

The `fill_value` for each field in `segArrNew` is applied in making the output  DataFrame. I used df.ix() to replace the filled-in tokens for what was masked out.