# Creating a Pandas DataFrame from a NumPy masked array?

Tags: pandas, numpy, missing-data

I am trying to create a Pandas `DataFrame` from a NumPy masked array, which I understand is a supported operation. This is an example of the source array:

```py
a = ma.array([(1, 2.2), (42, 5.5)],
             dtype=[('a',int),('b',float)],
             mask=[(True,False),(False,True)])
```

which outputs as:

```
masked_array(data=[(--, 2.2), (42, --)],
             mask=[( True, False), (False,  True)],
       fill_value=(999999, 1.e+20),
            dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```

Attempting to create a `DataFrame` with `pd.DataFrame(a)` returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-a4c5236a3cd4> in <module>
----> 1 pd.DataFrame(a)

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    636             # a masked array
    637             else:
--> 638                 data = sanitize_masked_array(data)
    639                 mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
    640                     data,

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/construction.py in sanitize_masked_array(data)
    452     """
    453     mask = ma.getmaskarray(data)
--> 454     if mask.any():
    455         data, fill_value = maybe_upcast(data, copy=True)
    456         data.soften_mask()  # set hardmask False if it was True

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _any(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, where)
     54     # Parsing keyword arguments is currently fairly slow, so avoid it for now
     55     if where is True:
---> 56         return umr_any(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     57     return umr_any(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, where=where)
     58 

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Is this operation indeed supported? Currently using Pandas 1.3.3 and NumPy 1.20.3.

**Update**

Is this supported?
According to the [Pandas documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html?highlight=masked%20array#from-a-list-of-dataclasses):

> Alternatively, you may pass a numpy.MaskedArray as the data argument to the DataFrame constructor, and its masked entries will be considered missing.

The code above was my asking the question "What will I get?" if I passed a NumPy masked array to Pandas, but that was the result I was hoping for. Above was the simplest example I could come up with.

I do expect each Series/column in Pandas to be of a single type.

**Update 2**

Anyone interested in this should probably see this Pandas [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42739); it's noted there that Pandas has "deprecated support for MaskedRecords".

Comment: Usually, using masked arrays in code that "knows nothing" about that subclass, will result in use of just the `data` part of the array, ignoring the mask.  Use `np.ma` functions or methods of the masked array.  What's the source for "which I understand is a supported operation"?

Comment: Questions like this should include the expected result.  This reduces ambiguities and need to followup questions or edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array has a simple dtype, the dataframe creation works (as documented):

```
In [320]: a = np.ma.array([(1, 2.2), (42, 5.5)],
     ...:    mask=[(True,False),(False,True)])
In [321]: a
Out[321]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, 2.2],
        [42.0, --]],
  mask=[[ True, False],
        [False,  True]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
In [322]: import pandas as pd
In [323]: pd.DataFrame(a)
Out[323]: 
      0    1
0   NaN  2.2
1  42.0  NaN
```

This `a` is (2,2), and the result is 2 rows, 2 columns

With the compound dtype, the shape is 1d:

```
In [326]: a = np.ma.array([(1, 2.2), (42, 5.5)],
     ...:              dtype=[('a',int),('b',float)],
     ...:              mask=[(True,False),(False,True)])
In [327]: a.shape
Out[327]: (2,)
```

The error is the result of a test on the mask.  `flexible type` refers to your compound `dtype`:

```
In [330]: a.mask.any()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-330-8dc32ee3f59d>", line 1, in <module>
    a.mask.any()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 57, in _any
    return umr_any(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

The documented pandas feature clearly does not apply to structured arrays.  Without studying the pandas code I can't say exactly what it's trying to do at this point, but it's clear the code was not written with structured arrays in mind.

The non-masked part does work, with the desired column dtypes:

```
In [332]: pd.DataFrame(a.data)
Out[332]: 
    a    b
0   1  2.2
1  42  5.5
```

Using the default `fill`:

```
In [344]: a.filled()
Out[344]: 
array([(999999, 2.2e+00), (    42, 1.0e+20)],
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<f8')])
In [345]: pd.DataFrame(a.filled())
Out[345]: 
        a             b
0  999999  2.200000e+00
1      42  1.000000e+20
```

I'd have to look more at `ma` docs/code to see if it's possible to apply a different fill to the two fields.  Filling with `nan` doesn't work for the int field.  `numpy` doesn't have `pandas'` int none.  I haven't worked enough with that pandas feature to know whether the resulting dtype is still int, or it is changed to object.

Anyways, you are pushing the bounds of both `np.ma` and `pandas` with this task.

### edit

The default fill_value is a tuple, one for each field:

```
In [350]: a.fill_value
Out[350]: (999999, 1.e+20)
```

So we can fill the fields differently, and make a frame from that:

```
In [351]: a.filled((-1, np.nan))
Out[351]: array([(-1, 2.2), (42, nan)], dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<f8')])
In [352]: pd.DataFrame(a.filled((-1, np.nan)))
Out[352]: 
    a    b
0  -1  2.2
1  42  NaN
```

Looks like I can make a structured array with a pandas dtype, and its associated fill_value:

```
In [363]: a = np.ma.array([(1, 2.2), (42, 5.5)],
     ...:              dtype=[('a',pd.Int64Dtype),('b',float)],
     ...:              mask=[(True,False),(False,True)],
                       fill_value=(pd.NA,np.nan))
In [364]: a
Out[364]: 
masked_array(data=[(--, 2.2), (42, --)],
             mask=[( True, False), (False,  True)],
       fill_value=(<NA>, nan),
            dtype=[('a', 'O'), ('b', '<f8')])

In [366]: pd.DataFrame(a.filled())
Out[366]: 
      a    b
0  <NA>  2.2
1    42  NaN
```

Comment: It would appear so! Thank you for the clarification. [np.ma.MaskedArray.filled](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.filled.html) does allow different fills between fields/types. It seems one solution is to manually fill for each column, convert to a `DataFrame`, then mask/assign `NaN` as needed based on those values in pandas-land. A few extra steps, but doable. Cheers.

Comment: Looks like we can use `pandas` dtypes and fill values in a structured array - see my edits.

Comment: I would not have thought to use Pandas types in NumPy arrays – happy to see that works. Great solution, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what would you expect to get? It would be ambiguous for pandas to convert your data.

If you want to get the original data:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(a.data)
    a    b
0   1  2.2
1  42  5.5
```

If you want to consider masked values invalid:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(a.filled(np.nan))
```

**BUT**, for this you should have all type float in the masked array

Comment: Ideally for float types the masked values would be NaN and for int values using the new(er) Int64 nullable Pandas type. I don't want an unmasked array.

Comment: In pandas, columns (Series) can have their own `dtype`.  That does not apply to elements of Series (unless you use `object` dtype through out).